# Why Image Uploads to folder but not insert into mysql DB?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, image-uploading

Hi Guys i got a Problem i upload an image to Upload Folder upload is working fine but he dont submit the  value into mysql database and i really dont know where the failure ist here ist the whole code.
Unique Value is id from the user and the field for the image name is company_logo.
My dashboard code:
The Form:

```
 <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
                           <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
                           </form>
```

JQuery Code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(document).ready(function() { 

            $('#photoimg').on('change', function()          { 
                       $("#preview").html('');
                $("#preview").html('<div class="spinner"></div>');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                        target: '#preview'
        }).submit();

            });
        }); 
</script>
```

And Finally The ajaximage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$valid_user_id = trim($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]);

if(isset($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]) && !empty($valid_user_id))
{

include "database_connection.php"; //Include the database connection script

//Check the logged in user information from the database
$check_user_details = mysql_query("select * from `signup_and_login_table` where `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"])."'");

//Get the logged in user info from the database
$get_user_details = mysql_fetch_array($check_user_details);

//Pass all the logged in user info to variables to easily display them when needed
$user_id = strip_tags($get_user_details['id']);
$firstname = strip_tags($get_user_details['firstname']);
$lastname = strip_tags($get_user_details['lastname']);
$company = strip_tags($get_user_details['company']);
$company_logo = strip_tags($get_user_details['company_logo']);
$email = strip_tags($get_user_details['email']);
$passwd = strip_tags($get_user_details['password']);

// User Id for Image Upload
$session_id = strip_tags($get_user_details['id']); 


$path = "uploads/";

$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp");
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
    {
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

        if(strlen($name))
            {
                list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                {
                if($size<(1024*1024))
                    {
                        $actual_image_name = time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 5).".".$ext;
                        $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name))
                            {
                            mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE signup_and_login_table SET company_logo='$actual_image_name' WHERE id='$session_id'");

                                echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";
                            }
                        else
                            echo "failed";
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Image file size max 1 MB";                    
                    }
                    else
                    echo "Invalid file format..";   
            }

        else
            echo "Please select image..!";

        exit;
    }

}
else
{
//Send every user who tries to access this page directly without valid session to the login page. 
//The login page is the door that every user needs to pass to this page
header("location: login.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is the `INSERT INTO` MySQL query?

Comment: I used Update query @PraveenKumar

Comment: Check if the UPDATE query directly on the phpMyAdmin or something, to check if it really updates the DB.

Comment: @user1607143 print the update query and run into phpmyadmin or query browser. what is the results let us know.

Comment: Mhh not working im using Mysql Front got an alternative for me ?

Comment: What's *Not Working*?

Comment: @user1607143 Post your generated update query? what you're getting in image name and id?

Comment: sorry works fine with my update query when i use the insert into it says duplicate entry for id value 1

Comment: @user1607143 if it works, then have you solved the problem?

Comment: no works in mysql front entered directly but not into the script itselfs

Comment: Your  ajaximage.php file

Comment: Please post your generated update query. I have already asked you.

Comment: sorrrry man im new to php how to output it with echo or some pls help me ?

Comment: could u gave me the syntax or code to do this ?

Comment: or what do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following sql query:
`INSERT INTO signup_and_login_table (company_logo, id) VALUES ('$actual_image_name', '$session_id')`

You've made instead a UPDATE Query, which only updates already EXISTING rows.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE signup_and_login_table SET company_logo='$actual_image_name' WHERE id=".$session_id);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Add error_reporting(E_ALL); before executing php script.

Comment: before the query executing you mean

Comment: like this `error_reporting(E_ALL);

         mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE signup_and_login_table SET company_logo='$actual_image_name' WHERE id=".$session_id);         
         echo "<img src='uploads/".$actual_image_name."'  class='preview'>";`

Comment: Ok do like this and also try to put at top of your current .php file.

Comment: in the ajaximage file or in the dashboard file?

Comment: nothing shown in the file or how to output the error ?